# Call a sub-function in a function to deal with a same file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am still fight with python copy and replace lines, a question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509810/can-not-make-the-replacement-work).  Basically, I want to statistics the number of a pattern in a section, and renew it in the line.  I think I have found the problem in my question: I call a sub-function to interate an same file in the main function, and the interation is messing up at time.  I am pretty new to programming, I don't know how to do this copy-statistics-replace-copy thing in another way.  Any suggestions or hints is welcome.

Here is part of code what I got now:

```
# sum number of keyframes
def sumKeys (sceneObj, objName):
    sceneObj.seek(0)
    block = []
    Keys = ""
    for line in sceneObj:
        if line.find("ObjectAlias " + objName + "\n") != -1:
            for line in sceneObj:
                if line.find("BeginKeyframe") != -1:
                    for line in sceneObj:
                        if line.find("default") != -1:
                            block.append(line.rstrip())
                            Keys = len(block)
                        elif line.find("EndKeyframe") != -1:
                            break
                    break
            break
    return (Keys)

# renew number of keyframes
def renewKeys (sceneObj, objName):
    sceneObj.seek(0)
    newscene = ""
    item = []
    for line in sceneObj:
        newscene += line
        for obj in objName:
            if line.find("ObjectAlias " + obj + "\n") != -1:
                for line in sceneObj:
                    if line.find("EndKeyframe") != -1:
                        newscene += line
                        break
                    if line.find("BeginKeyframe") != -1:
                        item = line.split()
                        newscene += item[0] + " " + str(sumKey(sceneObj, obj)) + " " + item[-1] + "\n"
                        continue
                    else:
                        newscene += line
    return (newscene)
```

Original:

```
lines
BeginObjects
lines
ObjectAlias xxx
lines
BeginKeyframe 34 12    ----> 34 is what I want to replace
lines
EndObject
BeginAnotherObjects
...
```

Goal:

```
lines
BeginObjects
lines
ObjectAlias xxx
lines
BeginKeyframe INT 12  ---->INT comes from sumKeys function
lines
EndObject
BeginAnotherObjects
...
```

Comment: So, you want to find the `BeginKeyframe` section in a file, count all lines between `BeginKeyframe` and `EndKeyframe` that contain `default`, and update the `BeginKeyframe` line to contain that number? Is that correct? A little bit hard to tell what exactly you want to do. Maybe you could clarify.

Comment: @sloth Yes, you're correct. there is many lines between **BeginKeyframe** and **EndKeyframe**, I need to count the **default** pattern and put into **BeginKeyframe** line to replace the original INT. I also need a function to deal with some other **object** (like ObjectAlias xxx). I am not an English guy, it's hard for me to say what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tell` and `seek` to move inside a file, so to do what you want to do, you could use something like this, which I hacked together:

```
import re

# so, we're looking for the object 'HeyThere'
objectname = 'HeyThere'

with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    pos = f.tell()
    found = False
    while line:

        # we only want to alter the part with the 
        # right ObjectAlias, so we use the 'found' flag
        if 'ObjectAlias ' + objectname in line:
            found = True
        if 'EndObject' in line:
            found = False

        if found and 'BeginKeyframe' in line:

            # we found the Keyframe part, so we read all lines 
            # until EndKeyframe and count each line with 'default'
            sub_line = f.readline()
            frames = 0
            while not 'EndKeyframe' in sub_line:
                if 'default' in sub_line:
                    frames += 1
                sub_line = f.readline()

            # since we want to override the 'BeginKeyframe', we
            # have to move back in the file to before this line
            f.seek(pos)

            # now we read the rest of the file, but we skip the
            # old 'BeginKeyframe' line we want to replace
            f.readline()
            rest = f.read()

            # we jump back to the right position again
            f.seek(pos)

            # and we write our new 'BeginKeyframe' line
            f.write(re.sub('\d+', str(frames), line, count=1))

            # and write the rest of the file
            f.write(rest)
            f.truncate()
            # nothing to do here anymore, just quit the loop
            break

        # before reading a new line, we keep track
        # of our current position in the file
        pos = f.tell()
        line = f.readline()
```

The comments pretty much explain what's going on.

Given an input file like

```
foo
bar
BeginObject
something
something
ObjectAlias NotMe
lines
more lines
BeginKeyframe 22 12   
foo
bar default
foo default
bar default
EndKeyframe
EndObject
foo
bar
BeginObject
something
something
ObjectAlias HeyThere
lines
more lines
BeginKeyframe 43243 12   
foo
bar default
foo default
bar default
foo default
bar default
foo default
bar
EndKeyframe
EndObject
```

it will replace the line

```
BeginKeyframe 43243 12
```

with

```
BeginKeyframe 6 12
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. Thanks for the code example, especially the comments. I spent a whole night try to understand it, it's a bit out of my reach. So the key is track line by line, right? But why I need readline? Seems a for loop interate don't need that. Also, where do I add the object interate to deal with multiple object replacement? In other word, how can I do the replace for other objects such as HeyYou, LookHere...

Comment: Try thinking of using `open` like opening the file in a graphical texteditor; with the mouse cursor at the start of the text. When you use readline, the cursor jumps to the end of the current row. Now, since we want to count some lines beneath the `BeginKeyframe` line, we have to keep reading lines, but we want to jump back to the `BeginKeyframe` line after reading all lines of that block (so we use `seek`). That's not possible with a for loop, since it "moves only forward". To actually handle more than one object, use `seek` again to jump back in the file instead of using `break`....

Comment: ...and change `if 'ObjectAlias ' + objectname in line:` to something like `if any('ObjectAlias ' + n in line for n in ['HeyYou', 'LookHere', 'WhatEver']):`

Comment: Thank you for help, specifically for the **for loop** comments. I will still try to complete the code so I can simply run `python script.py inputfile` to get the result.