# How to add loop to handle multiple object and multiple file in Python?

Tags: python

First of all, I am new to Python.
I had another question and an answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540616/call-a-sub-function-in-a-function-to-deal-with-a-same-file-in-pythonhttp://).
Form sloth's answer, I got the code to handle single file and single object:

```
import re

# so, we're looking for the object 'HeyThere'
objectname = 'HeyThere'

with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    pos = f.tell()
    found = False
    while line:

        # we only want to alter the part with the 
        # right ObjectAlias, so we use the 'found' flag
        if 'ObjectAlias ' + objectname in line:
            found = True
        if 'EndObject' in line:
            found = False

        if found and 'BeginKeyframe' in line:

            # we found the Keyframe part, so we read all lines 
            # until EndKeyframe and count each line with 'default'
            sub_line = f.readline()
            frames = 0
            while not 'EndKeyframe' in sub_line:
                if 'default' in sub_line:
                    frames += 1
                sub_line = f.readline()

            # since we want to override the 'BeginKeyframe', we
            # have to move back in the file to before this line
            f.seek(pos)

            # now we read the rest of the file, but we skip the
            # old 'BeginKeyframe' line we want to replace
            f.readline()
            rest = f.read()

            # we jump back to the right position again
            f.seek(pos)

            # and we write our new 'BeginKeyframe' line
            f.write(re.sub('\d+', str(frames), line, count=1))

            # and write the rest of the file
            f.write(rest)
            f.truncate()
            # nothing to do here anymore, just quit the loop
            break

        # before reading a new line, we keep track
        # of our current position in the file
        pos = f.tell()
        line = f.readline()
```

Due to lack of programming practice, I can't finish the code to handle multiple object and multiple file.
Say I change objectname to a list of objects and add code below "while line", the code just don't work anymore, something like this:

```
objectlist = ['GoodMoring', 'GoodAfternoon']
...

    while line:
        while objectlist:
            if 'ObjectAlias ' + objectlist in line:
            ...
```

I know it is a very basic question, sorry for that, but I still have to ask this question: How to make the code handle multiple object and multiple input file?

Comment: How are your objects and files related? Do you need to be searching every file for every object, or does each object correspond with a specific file?

Comment: @Blckknght The code that I got now only deal with **HeyThere** in **input.txt**, I need it to handle more object e.g. **GoodMoring** **GoodAfternoon** etc for any input file.

Comment: You are close, instead of while, change to for objectname in objectlist: if 'ObjectAlias ' + objectname in line:

Comment: @Skycc I have tried, then the code is frozen. Not working

Comment: I added a answer, check those out if works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for multiple objects, you can try below

```
for objectname in objectlist:
    if 'ObjectAlias ' + objectname in line:
        found = True
```

Or better one is to use any, [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) Return True if any element of the iterable is true

```
found = any('ObjectAlias ' + objectname in line for objectname in objectlist)
```

Full code as below

```
objectlist = ['GoodMoring', 'GoodAfternoon']

# can add another for loop here for list of file to process
# for ff in os.listdir():
#       with open(ff, 'r+') as f
with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    pos = f.tell()
    found = False
    while line:
        # if found already true skip checking
        found = found or any('ObjectAlias ' + objectname in line for objectname in objectlist)
        if 'EndObject' in line:
            found = False

        if found and 'BeginKeyframe' in line:
            # we found the Keyframe part, so we read all lines 
            # until EndKeyframe and count each line with 'default'
            sub_line = f.readline()
            frames = 0
            while not 'EndKeyframe' in sub_line:
                if 'default' in sub_line:
                    frames += 1
                sub_line = f.readline()

            pos2 = f.tell() # save pos to continue for next Keyframe if there is 
            # pos2 should store position of EndKeyframe now

            # since we want to override the 'BeginKeyframe', we
            # have to move back in the file to before this line
            f.seek(pos)

            # skip read rest of file coz we wanna continue next Keyframe

            # and we write our new 'BeginKeyframe' line
            f.write(re.sub('\d+', str(frames), line, count=1))

            f.seek(pos2) # restore pos because we wanna continue to process next Leyfram if there is any 

            # skip write the rest of the file
            # don't truncate and break here bcoz we wanna continue

        # before reading a new line, we keep track
        # of our current position in the file
        pos = f.tell()
        line = f.readline()
```

Comment: No idea why not working, lets wait for better answer from other expert

Comment: Any error msg ? Hang ? The code i suspect hang at while not 'EndKeyframe' in sub_line part. And how was your input file looks like

Comment: No msg, just hang. [sloth's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540616/call-a-sub-function-in-a-function-to-deal-with-a-same-file-in-python) has some input example.

Comment: checkout updated full code, i have tested working with input example you gave me

Comment: now it works well, I am bad in promgramming, and still try to understand it, thanks for help.

Comment: glad it works, added more comment hope it help your understanding

Comment: Sorry for bother, for some reason, I don't want to use re module to write over the original file, how can I get this work done by writing into a new file? Thanks

Comment: The easiest way without touching existing code is to copy target file into new file then run existing code with new file instead

Comment: This is what I have done now. The link in my above comment, my original code is copy line by line into an new file, that is what I most want. Can this be done in current code?

Comment: A bit off topic here and not clear on what you want, probably you wanna start a new question on this

Comment: I have posted an new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966917/replace-string-without-python-re-module)