# Replace string without python re module?

Tags: python

Say my file looks like this:

```
foo
bar
BeginObject
something
something
ObjectAlias NotMe
lines
more lines
BeginKeyframe 22 12   
foo
bar default
foo default
bar default
EndKeyframe
EndObject
foo
bar
BeginObject
something
something
ObjectAlias HeyThere
lines
more lines
BeginKeyframe 43243 12   
foo
bar default
foo default
bar default
foo default
bar default
foo default
bar
EndKeyframe
EndObject
```

I want the line:

```
BeginKeyframe 43243 12
```

be replaced with:

```
BeginKeyframe 6 12
```

**Note:** 6 is the count of "default" bewteen BeginKeyframe and EndKeyframe

My first version of python code have some interation issues. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540616/call-a-sub-function-in-a-function-to-deal-with-a-same-file-in-pythonhttp://)
Thanks sloth and Skycc, an improved version is working. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571549/how-to-add-loop-to-handle-multiple-object-and-multiple-file-in-python)
The suitation by now is the improved code use re module to implementation, that is not what I want, I prefer to copy original file line by line into an new file without over write the original file.
So my question is how to improve Skycc's code?

```
objectlist = ['GoodMoring', 'GoodAfternoon']
with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    pos = f.tell()
    found = False
    while line:
        found = found or any('ObjectAlias ' + objectname in line for objectname in objectlist)
        if 'EndObject' in line:
            found = False
        if found and 'BeginKeyframe' in line:
            sub_line = f.readline()
            frames = 0
            while not 'EndKeyframe' in sub_line:
                if 'default' in sub_line:
                    frames += 1
                sub_line = f.readline()
            pos2 = f.tell()
            f.seek(pos)
            f.write(re.sub('\d+', str(frames), line, count=1))
            f.seek(pos2)
        pos = f.tell()
        line = f.readline()
```

Comment: nothing to do with re mod, you need open another file for write like `of = open('foo', 'wb')` line and replace `f.write(re.sub, ...` with `of.write(...`

Comment: Then, the output file only have the line be changed? What about the reset unchanged lines? Sorry for simple question, since I am very new to programming.

Comment: indeed, it is simple, you could output unchanged lines to `of` as well: `if found and ...: of.write(re.sub(..., line)); else of.write(line)`

Comment: @georgexsh: Not that simple for me. Add else statement lead to losing lines bewteen BeginKeyframe and EndKeyframe.

Comment: Why don't you want to use regular expressions?

Comment: you might wanna update your questions with requirements that you only interest on frame block with matching ObjectAlias in objectlist, most people not aware of this if they are not refer to the old question post. And it still puzzling us why without the `re` module

Comment: I don't know much about programming, I just want to find the way I can understand. Also, I don't mind to learning more it, is **re** better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just open the input.txt with `'r'` mode for read only, and open another file output.txt with `'w'` mode to write to new file. And don't need the `seek` and `tell` as well, just process it line by line while reading input file.

A buffer is use to keep the the lines once BeginKeyFrame found. Release the buffer to ouput file when EndObject found.

Quick edit the code as below, should works but might not so elegant and pythonic

```
objectlist = ['GoodMoring', 'GoodAfternoon']
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
    found = False
    begin_frame = False
    buffer = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ObjectAlias'):
            found = any('ObjectAlias ' + objectname in line for objectname in objectlist)
        elif line.startswith('EndObject'):
            if found and begin_frame:
                # modify and write all buffer into output file
                buffer[0] = buffer[0].replace(buffer[0].split()[1], str(frames), 1)
                for i in buffer:
                    fo.write(i)
            buffer = [] # clear buffer
            found = False
            begin_frame = False
        elif line.startswith('BeginKeyframe'):
            begin_frame = True
            frames = 0

        if found and begin_frame:
            buffer.append(line)
            if 'default' in line:
                frames += 1
        else:
            fo.write(line)
```

Comment: Not work. **line 14, in <module> IndexError: list index out of range** in python 2.7.12.

Comment: ops, it work for the example input but it didn't take care the scenario when ObjectAlias not in objectlist, try out updated code

Comment: Ok, it works now. **Q1:** Why so different from your older code? **Q2:** Why use for instead of while? **Q3:** Why no seek and tell anymore? Also, please more comments to help understand. Thanks

Comment: A1: the big difference is mainly due to like i mention we don't need `tell` and `seek` as we don't need modify in line with read. A2: we use while loop with `readline` in old code as we wanna avoid changing the file pointer while iterating over the file object. Now we can simply iterate over the file object as we are processing input file line by line and write to output file now.

Comment: A3: `seek` and `tell` is for changing current file read pointer, this is not applicable when we creating new file now unless we wanna go over count the frames 1st, then go back to BeginKeyFrame, it can be done like this as well but i feel this make things more complicated to go back and forth

Answer (score 1):

full code goes:

```python
interested_objects = ['HeyThere', 'anotherone',]

buff = []
obj_flag = False
keyframe_flag = False

with open('in') as f, open ('out', 'w') as of:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()

        if line.startswith('ObjectAlias'):
            assert not obj_flag
            assert not keyframe_flag
            if line.split()[1] in interested_objects:
                obj_flag = True

        if not obj_flag:
            print >>of, line
            continue

        if 'EndObject' in line:
            assert not keyframe_flag
            obj_flag = False

        if 'BeginKeyframe' in line:
            assert not keyframe_flag
            keyframe_flag = True

        if keyframe_flag:
            buff.append(line)
        else:
            print >>of, line

        if 'EndKeyframe' in line:
            parts = buff[0].split()
            new_line = '{} {} {}'.format(parts[0], len(buff)-2, parts[2])
            print >>of, new_line
            print >>of, '\n'.join(buff[1:])
            buff = []
            keyframe_flag = False
```

Comment: Thanks the improved code. As I say before, Can this be done without re module? Something like read one line from original file, write it into an new file, just like my first version [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540616/call-a-sub-function-in-a-function-to-deal-with-a-same-file-in-python) does. I'm sorry for bother, but I have my reason need that.

Comment: why not, haha, changed, but i am curious about the reason behind.

Comment: I am very new to programming, by now I do think regular expressions is a bit out of my reach. I will hack it in time. Also, I find your code can't deal with mutiple object, would you please update the code like my current one? From my another question, for loop can't handle my suitation. Also, some comments to explain will be lovely. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "mutiple objects"?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571549/how-to-add-loop-to-handle-multiple-object-and-multiple-file-in-python)

Comment: @Tian still no idea what is your problem with "multi objects", all i can see is there are some Keyframe and Object sections, and they are not interlaced.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. Since this is only a part of my code, before this part, I added some lines into serveral object sections in the file with other code, and I need to recount "default" and replace the original number after "BeginKeyframe" of the right objects, so I think it's best to process the right objects but not all objects. I am still very new to programming, and I have to spent some time to figure your code out. I think your code process every object in the file, right?

Comment: @Tian how to identify object to be processed, by `ObjectAlias` ?

Answer (score 0):

The file temp.txt contains your input. There's no actual need to use "re" module for these simple operations.

```
asource = open('temp.txt').read().split('\n')
aframe = -1

def wrapFrame():
    global aframe
    if aframe < 0: return
    asource[aframe][1] = str(asource[aframe][1])
    asource[aframe] = ' '.join(asource[aframe])
    aframe = -1

for i in xrange(len(asource)):
    aline = asource[i]

    if aframe > -1:
        if 'default' in aline:
            asource[aframe][1] += 1
        elif 'EndKeyframe' in aline:
            wrapFrame()
    elif 'BeginKeyframe' in aline:
        aframe = i
        asource[i] = aline.split(' ')
        asource[i][1] = 0

wrapFrame()

asource = '\n'.join(asource)
print asource
```

Comment: Haha, this one is more complicated than re module for me. I am still learning python hardly, but it needs time.

Comment: What this algoryithm does: splits the input file into the list of lines, then locates first 'BeginKeyrame' and pools every 'default' to it unless 'EndKeyframe' is met. Then packs it all into one text again.